# RelativeLayout - dragging custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view with an onTouch() listener.
This view is added to a RelativeLayout so:

```
CustomView mv = new CustomView(mActivity);
RelativeLayout rl = ((RelativeLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_layout));
rl.addView(mv);
```

I wish the view to be dragged with the finger under API8, preferably by code residing in the view's own onTouch() listener.

It's probably a few lines of code along the edge of setPadding() or RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(), but after one hour of trial and error, I can't find it.

Any clues? Thanks a lot.

PS: The onTouch works like it should, I just don't know what lines of code I could add to it that would move the view.

Comment: did you try with setTop() and setLeft();

Comment: The doc clearly states there is no warranty they will behave as hoped. I'd therefore rather not.

Comment: I think ther's something like setX() setY() but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use FrameLayout and then change margin of your CustomView like this:

```
LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mv.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
mv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as you suggested, it required changing a TranslationAnimation I had, as it misbehaved with the framelayout for some reason. Now it works, still why couldn't it work in relativelayout?